# Etymology for the phrase, "on a lark."

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology for the phrase, "on a lark" or "for a lark?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lark#Etymology_2) and [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=lark&searchmode=none) say that the origin of *lark* in the meaning "frolic, prank" is not clear. Wiktionary puts it like this:

> Origin uncertain, either
>
> - from (notably northern) English dialect *lake/laik* (“to play”) (c.1300, from Old Norse *leika* (“to play (as opposed to work)”)), with intrusive -r- common in southern British dialect; or
> - shortening of *skylark* (1809), sailors' slang, "play roughly in the rigging of a ship", because the common European larks were proverbial for high-flying; Dutch has a similar idea in *speelvogel* (“playbird, a person of markedly playful nature”).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize the issue was even in doubt.  "Lark" has the sense of an impulsive, joyful, almost random flit, like the swoop of a lark. "Prank" carries a connotation of malice, of playing an unkind trick on someone -- whereas, if there's a victim, that's not a "lark".  A "frolic" is energetic (to my ears) almost to the point of being laborious.  As for the Dutch word -- there's a very similar word in German, *spielvogel*, "game-bird" but the game in this case is killing the bird!

Answer (score 2):

The OED's earliest citation is for the noun *lark*, in in *Lexicon Balatronicum: a dictionary of buckish slang, university wit, and pickpocket eloquence* (1811):

> *Lark*, a piece of merriment. People playing together jocosely.

Their etymology is:

> Possibly it may represent the northern *lake* v.1 [To exert oneself, move quickly, leap, spring; hence, to fight. Obs.], as heard by sporting men from Yorkshire jockeys or grooms; the sound /læək/ , which is written *lairk* in Robinson's *Whitby Glossary* and in dialect books, would to a southern hearer more naturally suggest ‘lark’ than ‘lake’ as its equivalent in educated pronunciation. On the other hand, it is quite as likely that the word may have originated in some allusion to *lark* n.1 [the bird]; compare the similar use of *skylark* vb., which is found a few years earlier (1809).